# How to give product images external url in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I Need to use product images in external server in magento 1.9.0.1. how can i give external image url to the product. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done in the meantime:

Edit app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml In the file you'll find two instances of `img src`, for each of those two `src` attributes I changed the value to:

```
src="<?php echo $_product->getSmallImage() ?>"
```

Edit app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml Search for `id="image"` changed the `src` attribute to be:

```
src="'.$_product->getImage().'"
```

In my product CSV, I'm loading the image and small_image values accordingly (as being the entire url including protocol and host etc).

There are undoubtedly other places where this similar changes should be made (such as wishlist pages), but at the moment, that gets the proper images showing in the grid data and product details view which is good enough for me for now.